# HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found - URL Rewrite - IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I am building an application using ASP.NET MVC + AngularJS. Now to make API calls through AngularJS, I am using URL rewrite because APIs are hosted on different servers.

but it gives me 404.4 error. I checked the trace for the request and patterns are matching fine. It is trying rewrite to the server url, but then it gives 404.4 error.

I have also added  in my web.config. My rewrite rule is as follows:

```
<rewrite>
      <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTP_Authorization"/>
      </allowedServerVariables>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Api Call" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="quote/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://<server>/pc/service/edge/quote/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
          <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTP_Authorization" value="Basic <key>" />
          </serverVariables>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="quote/(.*)" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

[image: Url Rewrite 400.4 Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to install IIS Application Request Routing: Visit https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing
2. Check the “Enable proxy” checkbox located in Application Request Routing feature view is IIS Manager
   [image]

[image]